# ORA-04098: trigger 'PFA.TRIGG_MODIF_ADH' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle

The trigger is created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trigg_modifadh
BEFORE UPDATE OF noAdh,nom,prenom,ncin,dateadh 
ON adherent 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20489,
    '  La modification sur ses coordonnées de adherent est  interdite !!! ');
END;
```

But when I test it doesn't work and throws error:

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'PFA.TRIGG_MODIF_ADH' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

and this code-20489 I didn't use ever

Comment: Don't forget to ask a question, in English!

Comment: Please explain what this code should do and what the problem is, in English.

Comment: The error is against `TRIGG_MODIF_ADH`. You've shown us `TRIGG_MODIFADH`, without the second underscore. You've probably had several attempts at creating this, and changed the name along the way. Check and fix/drop the other trigger. (You can query `user_errors` to see what the actual problem is.)

Comment: [Quick demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d108dd215e71441c6ace89b6d6b09d11) showing the two similarly-named triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Something *bad* has happened to the underlying table.

For example:

Creating a table:

```
SQL> create table adherent(noadh number, nom number, prenom number, ncin number, dateadh number);

Table created.
```

Creating a trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trigg_modifadh
  2  BEFORE UPDATE OF noAdh,nom,prenom,ncin,dateadh
  3   ON adherent
  4  FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20489,'  La modification sur ses coordonnées de adherent est  interdite !!! ');
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Dropping one of columns:

```
SQL> alter table adherent drop column dateadh;

Table altered.
```

Updating a table will fire the trigger:

```
SQL> update adherent set noadh = 1;
update adherent set noadh = 1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'SCOTT.TRIGG_MODIFADH' is invalid and failed re-validation


SQL>
```

See? Check the table.